# mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli

so I'm trying to take all the ofice_id and pass them to this function to handle all the office but I need to store the result in $result_arry[] and that what I have  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in
I'm sure the query is working and everything is good but couldn't fix this

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE AN_M(IN id VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

DECLARE start_date date;
DECLARE price_m DOUBLE;
DECLARE months int;

SELECT contract_start , price_month  INTO start_date  , price_m
FROM rent

/* here we take the diff betwen months*/ 
set months =TIMESTAMPDIFF(month, start_date, GetDate());

set @to_pay = months * price_m ;

SELECT COUNT(office_id) 
FROM rent
where price_pid > @to_pay;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

PHP script:

```
<?php

require('DB.php');

$sql_rented = "SELECT office_id as id from rent ;";
$rented = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_rented);

$id = array();
$result_arry =array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rented) ) {
  $id[] = $row;
}

foreach ( $id as $value )
{
  $value = implode($value);
  
  $sql = "CALL AN_M('$value');";
  $s = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($s) ) {
    $result_arry[] = $row;
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannae store more than 1 value in a variable..

Comment: AT first glance you dont need a procedure for this and you can do it with a query. It would help if you show some data and expected results

Comment: You're missing a `;` after `FROM rent` in the procedure.

Comment: The `AN_M()` procedure doesn't take any parameters. What is it supposed to do with the `'$value'` argument?

Comment: it has and still didnt work